# Export Classes, Methods, & Parameters

Tags: visual-c++, vb6

Is there a program, hopefully free, that can export/print the classes inside an object browser in Visual Studio 6 or Visual C++?  It would be great if it included the methods & parameters inside the classes as well.

Thanks

Comment: What have you found so far?

Comment: Ebrowse - [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ebrowse.html)

Comment: Cool, you should try that.

Comment: That didn't help much, which is why I asked the question here.  I'm looking for someone who has actually done this to comment. Thanks

Comment: The "OLE-COM Object Viewer" from the Windows SDK?

Comment: @MarkJ - This is so close.  It lists all of the classes and methods of the .dll, but I cannot print them as a list as their is no funtionality for it.  It also does not show the parameters for the methods.  Thanks though.